# SSIS ERROR "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type"

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ssis, etl, script-task

I'm using ssis to parse file txt into sql server. I use script task to convert a string example `"20190523100520"` (type :yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss) to datetime (it's data type in table sql ).

But I get the error:

> [OLE DB Destination [68]] Error: "There was an error with OLE DB
>       Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].Columns[NewEffectiveTS_NXX_X] on
>
> OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]. The column status 
>       returned was: "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type.

In script task, tag inputs and outputs, i use database timestamp `[DT_DBTIMESTAMP]` type for Columns `[NewEffectiveTS_NXX_X]`

Everyone help me. Thank you so much!

Comment: The problem was fixed, thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert this value to datetime datatype inside the script you can use `DateTime.ParseExact()` function:

```
DateTime.ParseExact([Column],"yyyyMMddHHmmss",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Because the string value `20190523100520` cannot be implicitly converted to datetime by mapping a column of type string to another of type datetime.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to redirect the error output to a flat file and check if the rows contains wrong data in the datetime field.If you cant find any problem try to put the string in a valid format by inserting "/"," " and ":" for example your string "20190523100520" will become "2019/05/23 10:05:20"